# ImportError: cannot import name 'Students' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying out python Django version 4.2.2 to do a project for an activity, I would like to ask what seems to be the problem because whenever i run my project file in VSCode terminal I get the following errors

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in 
run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked       
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed     
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\runapp\amsdjangocrud\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('', include('amsapps.urls')),
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include    
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked       
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed     
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\runapp\amsapps\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\runapp\amsapps\views.py", line 4, in <module>       
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Students
ImportError: cannot import name 'Students' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' (C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py)
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django.db import models

class Students(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.course}, {self.contact}, {self.address}, {self.gender}, {self.lastname}, {self.firstname}, {self.id_number}, {self.student_id},'

class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey('Status',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'assignment'

class Instructor(models.Model):
    instructor_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'instructor'
```

Here are my import and a function on my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Students
from django.contrib.auth.models import Assignment

def main(request, id):
    joined_data = Assignment.objects.get(id>=1)
    return render(request, 'amsapp/main.html', {'data': joined_data })
```

I am confuse on where I seem to go wrong, any help would be appreciated

I tried inserting the models in my admin.py in this format:

```
from .models import (
    Assignment,
    Instructor,
    Student,
    Subject
)
```

But the problem is still there

Comment: Why are you importing your models from django.contrib.auth.models? This file contains Django defined models like default User. You should import your models from <app_name>.models file

Comment: You must learn Python language basics before learning Django. This document should teach you everything about importing: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Students' from 'django.contrib.auth.models'

This tells you already what exactly is not working in your code. Everything that you are importing from `django.<...>` you are importing from the official django package. Meaning that code is not written by you but is installed via your package manager and is originally written by the django team.

Having said that you instead want to import your "own" models. In case you are importing within the same app you can write the exact same import statement as you have already done in admin.py. Just copy and paste the import statement from admin.py to views.py.

```py
from .models import Assignment, Student
```

In case you need to import something from another app go with this syntax:

```py
from <appname>.models import <modelname>
from shop.models import Product
```

**Note:** In case you want to utilize djangos [Authentication System](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth) (I mention that because this is the code that lives in `django.contrib.auth`) you should maybe consider to inherit your `Student`model from `AbstractUser`. Maybe that was your initial goal?

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class Students(AbstractUser):
```

This would give your `Student`s all the fields and functionality from djangos built-in authentication system.